# How can I delete a specific cell using .remove() in python

Tags: python

Say I have a list that looks like this

```py
f = [['person','place','item'],['george','home','phone']]
```

how would I search through that list and delete a specific cell using f.remove()
I have tried:

```py
f.remove('item')
```

which should remove `'item'` but instead it returns the error

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: `f[0].remove('item')`

Comment: Do you also want to remove the corresponding element in each of the lists?

Comment: Also, I suggest that you learn about dictionaries. They are a much better structure when you want to label values with a name.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No I was using that as a poorly made example I just wanted to remove one cell

Comment: It looks like you are storing rows and columns in a 2D list. Do you know that the thing you want to remove is always in the first row?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am using a 2d list because it is easier to write to a csv file.  The item will never be first that was just in my example but someone had an answer that was full proof no matter what column it was

Comment: @SeaverOlson I suggest you check out `csv.DictWriter` that writes a list of dicts to a CSV file.

Comment: Also, the accepted answer is right only if you want to replace the entire first row with `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to do this. You need to put the if statement inside the inner loop.

```
f = [['person','place','item'],['george','home','phone']]

f = [[a for a in x if a != 'item'] for x in f]
```

The output of this will be:

```
[['person', 'place'], ['george', 'home', 'phone']]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
f = [['person','place','item'],['george','home','phone']]
new_f = []
for x in f:
    temp_list = []
    for a in x:
        if a != 'item':
            temp_list.append(a)
    new_f.append(temp_list)
print (new_f)
```

The output of both will be the same.

Comment: Thank you I double-checked the answer I decided was correct and it did not work in the case that the list was not empty yet. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: This solution will work irrespective of whether the value exists in the original list or not. For example, if we replace `item` with `apple`, it will print the full list as `apple` is not in the list. With `list.remove('apple')`, you need to solve for `ValueError`

Answer (score 2):

you have list of lists, if you want to remove item from 1st list, you should do the following way:

```
f[0].remove('item')
```

`.remove()` is `inplace` operation and doesn't return any value. i.e it will change the list itself, so after above operation your list will be:

```
print(f)

# output [['person', 'place'], ['george', 'home', 'phone']]
```

for second list:

```
f[1].remove('home')
```

Comment: list.remove('val') can result in ValueError. The solution for the OP should be complete. Can you use the try:except or if statement to ensure this does not result in an exception situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
f[0].remove('item')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using list comprehension

```
f=[x.remove('item')  if 'item' in x else x for x in f]
```

Comment: x.remove('item') will return a None. So you will NOT get the desired result. you need send all values of x except `item`

Answer (score 0):

In your example `f` is a two-dimensional list, so all the items in `f` are also lists, and `item` is not one of them. Depending on your use case, I can see multiple ways of interpreting "remove":

If you want your resulting list to be `[['person','place'],['george','home','phone']]`, you can use

```
f[0].remove('item')
```

If you want your resulting list to be `[['person','place'],['george','home']]` (i.e. removing the whole "column" from the 2D list), then you should first find the index you want to remove, and then use `del` based on the index:

```py
index = f[0].index('item')
for row in f:
  del row[index]
```